# Create Smooth concurrent graphic based on time and position data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

First I want to say that I can create a matplotlib animation for what I want, however it is far too laggy, and is hard to jump to different times etc even with a different plot with a slider (there is just so much data).

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamp objects in the index, and for trial sake 4 players in the frame each with their positions at that time. Note that for 20 players I am going to have a dataframe which is around 4 million rows.

```
Timestamp                    Player Rotated Lat Rotated Lon
2018-11-11 16:22:21.999993600   G   -15.89769   84.714795
2018-11-11 16:22:21.999993600   W   -15.897637  84.714784
2018-11-11 16:22:21.999993600   K   -15.897617  84.714621
2018-11-11 16:22:21.999993600   Y   -15.897638  84.714787
2018-11-11 16:22:22.099958400   K   -15.897618  84.714623
2018-11-11 16:22:22.099958400   Y   -15.897691  84.714796
2018-11-11 16:22:22.099958400   W   -15.897619  84.714626
2018-11-11 16:22:22.200009600   Y   -15.897693  84.714794
2018-11-11 16:22:22.200009600   G   -15.897639  84.714788
2018-11-11 16:22:22.200009600   K   -15.897693  84.714802
2018-11-11 16:22:22.299974400   W   -15.897692  84.714796
2018-11-11 16:22:22.299974400   G   -15.897622  84.714629
2018-11-11 16:22:22.299974400   Y   -15.897639  84.714791
2018-11-11 16:22:22.299974400   K   -15.897694  84.714799
2018-11-11 16:22:22.400025600   G   -15.89764   84.714794
2018-11-11 16:22:22.400025600   K   -15.897622  84.714632
2018-11-11 16:22:22.400025600   Y   -15.897692  84.714804
2018-11-11 16:22:22.400025600   W   -15.897623  84.714635
2018-11-11 16:22:22.499990400   Y   -15.897692  84.714806
2018-11-11 16:22:22.499990400   W   -15.897694  84.714802
2018-11-11 16:22:22.499990400   G   -15.897641  84.714795
2018-11-11 16:22:22.499990400   K   -15.897694  84.714808
```

I have rotated the latitudes and longitudes to make the field parallel with the x-axis already, and I assume I might have to do a forward/backwards fill on the timestamps which do not include all the players positions.

I was wondering if there were any python libraries that have already solved this problem of plotting the points real-time and had the ability to jump to different times to see where each player is on the field. Then I could jump to the start of the game in the graphic and the video, and then play them concurrently. As I said above, matplotlib animation is not viable here because there are so many points and I want the graphic to be smooth and concurrent.

Ideally I would be able to play the graphic like a video, so go to any time in the game and the 11 players on the field would have their positions marked at that time. Then I could press 'play' and the players would start moving as they did in the game at that time.

Edit:

Here is what I would like the graphic to look like and be able to have a time slider to go throughout the game. However, I did this in matplotlib and once again don't think this is the right way to go about this problem. [image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://pypi.org/project/mpl-animationmanager/

Comment: As far as your dataframe goes, I wonder if pivoting the data such that the players are columns and the values are `shapely.geometry.Point` objects would have any beneficial affect on performance.